# Magento sales report via customer group

Tags: orders, reports

how can i get sales report based on customer group

Bacially i want to add extra filter customer group to amdin > report > sales > order

How i can do it pls help , if possible via module observer will be helpful

Comment: could not figure out how to start do , which observer to call for that

Comment: I think you want to start here: \Mage_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form_Order. In the backend are a lot of events "missing", so I don't think you can avoid rewrites

Comment: can i do it via any observer ??

Comment: I don'T think so, but I simple don't know. Search for an event. If you find one, use it. If you don't, rewrite, add your own and then use this

Answer (score 2):

Adding the form filter field can be done easily via observer like this:
In your module `config.xml`

```
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>

            <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <yourmodule_append_custom_sales_report_filters>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                        <method>appendCustomSalesReportFilters</method>
                    </yourmodule_append_custom_sales_report_filters>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_html_before>

        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

In your Observer:

```
public function appendCustomSalesReportFilters($_observer)
{
    $_block = $_observer->getBlock();
    if (!isset($_block)) {
        return $this;
    }
    //Mage_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form_Order
    Mage::log($_block->getType());
    if ($_block->getType() == 'sales/adminhtml_report_filter_form_order') {
        $_form = $_block->getForm();
        $fieldset = $_form->getElement('base_fieldset');
        $fieldset->addField('some_field', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'some_field',
            'label' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Some Field'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Some Field'),
        )
        );
    }
}
```

This will add your custom field to the filter form of the Sales Report.
[image: Sales Report Filters Block]

Further, try to do the same to add the grid column.
Afterwards, check if filter works by default, as I think the grid collection collects the grid columns and applies the filters from the form by default.
If not, you'll have to rewrite some collection.

Answer (score 0):

## About GridControl

Just change customer_id to group_id. Then you have the group_id.

But I think you can't add the customer group name. The problem is, that you need to first join from sales_flat_order_grid to sales_flat_order and then to customer_group. The second join can't be made at the moment. At least I didn't find fast a way. You are welcome to read in https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl/blob/master/src/app/code/community/FireGento/GridControl/Model/Observer.php maybe you find a way.

If not feel free to send a PR to join tables without fields :-)